# Sum duplicated rows on a multi-index pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Hello I'm having troubles dealing with Pandas. I'm trying to sum duplicated rows on a multiindex Dataframe.
I tryed with `df.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()` , also with `df.stack().reset_index().groupby(['year', 'product']).sum()` and some others, but I cannot get it to work. 
I'd also like to add every unique product for each given year and give them a 0 value if they weren't listed.

Example: dataframe with multi-index and 3 different products (A,B,C):

```
                  volume1    volume2
year   product
2010   A          10         12
       A          7          3
       B          7          7
2011   A          10         10
       B          7          6
       C          5          5
```

Expected output : if there are duplicated products for a given year then we sum them. 
If one of the products isnt listed for a year, we create a new row full of 0.

```
                  volume1     volume2
year   product
2010   A          17          15
       B          7           7
       C          0           0
2011   A          10          10
       B          7           6
       C          5           5
```

Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sum` with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = df.sum(level=[0,1]).unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
#same as
#df = df.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum().unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
```

Alternative with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = df.sum(level=[0,1])
#same as
#df = df.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels, names = df.index.names)
df = df.reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
```

Alternative1, thanks @Wen:

```
df = df.sum(level=[0,1]).unstack().stack(dropna=False)
```

---

```
print (df)
              volume1  volume2
year product                  
2010 A             17       15
     B              7        7
     C              0        0
2011 A             10       10
     B              7        6
     C              5        5
```

Comment: Maybe you can add df.sum(level=[0,1]).unstack().stack(dropna=False)

Comment: This answer is perfect.  A very subtle point is that `mux` could also have been created prior to the `sum`.  What this means is that the same solution could have been easily pipelined with `df.sum(level=[0, 1]).reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels, names=df.index.names), fill_value=0)`

Answer (score 3):

You can make the second level of the index a `CategoricalIndex` and when you use `groupby` it will include all of the categories.

```
df.index.set_levels(pd.CategoricalIndex(df.index.levels[1]), 1, inplace=True)
df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).sum().fillna(0, downcast='infer')

              volume1  volume2
year product                  
2010 A             17       15
     B              7        7
     C              0        0
2011 A             10       10
     B              7        6
     C              5        5
```